# Are there Leaflet templates for computer illeterates?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapquest

I would need to build a simple sharable map where users can draw things with some data attached (a link, an email...). I can see many other uses for other computer illiterates. Thanks for not closing

Answer (score 0):

MapQuest.js can be used with Leaflet Draw tools as shown [here](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.3/examples/map-with-leaflet-draw/) to allow users to draw on the map.